# What was the second platform supported by SAP?

Tags: history, software, mainframe, application-program

SAP, the well-known ERP software company, started out in the 1970s, with the first version of their software running on IBM mainframes, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAP_R/2

> What was unique about R/2 was that it was a packaged software application that processed real-time on a mainframe computer taking advantage of [Time Sharing Option](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Sharing_Option) and integrated all of an enterprise's functions...

At that time, the IBM 360 line of mainframes was the premier business computing platform, so it made sense to start there. Obviously, they eventually ported their code to other platforms.

What was the second platform their code ran on, and when?

Comment: Might not have been so much of a different (Hardware) Plattform, but adapted to a different OS - as in BS2000 on Siemens System 7.000. Their hardware was mostly (on user side fully) /370 compatible, but the OS a complete different beast. A way more integrated Environment than IBM's offerings.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to [SAP’s company history page,](https://www.sap.com/about/company/history/1972-1980.html) they began supporting Siemens hardware in 1977.  Siemens AG, another German company, was not considered one of “IBM and the Seven Dwarfs.”   I suspect, but am not sure, that this was the [Siemens 4004 and 7.000](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/641770.641772) series of mainframes, which were based on a design from RCA compatible with the IBM System/360 (in unprivileged, not privileged, mode), and which ran an OS by Siemens called BS2000.

Answer (score 8):

According to the German version of the Wikipedia page you linked to, SAP R/2 was released in 1979 and ran on "IBM's operating systems MVS and VSE as well as BS2000 from Siemens".

Its predecessor R1 was relased in 1975 and was used on IBM System/360, no other plattforms mentioned.